# Matlab: Scaling a range

Tags: matlab, matrix, distribution

`x = randn(100,1)` creates a sequence of numbers of Normal distribution in the range [-1,1].

I want to assign characters or numbers such as '1','0','-1' by representing the above range in 3 sub-regions, [-1,0,1]. I cannot understand how I can do so. I am able to do for Uniform distribution when `x = rand(100,1)` into 3 sub-regions `[0,1/3],(1/3,2/3],(2/3,1]`

```
x = rand(100,1)
for i =1:100
if x(i) <1/3 
 x(i) = -1;
elseif x(i) < 2/3
  x(i) = 0;
else x(i)=1;
end
end
```

Can somebody please show how I can apply the same technique when the numbers are generated from a Normal distribution?

Comment: a. By definition, normal random numbers are between -inf and +inf.  b. what are your subregions? [-inf -1],(-1 1),[1 inf]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tal said, a Normal distribution ranges from `-Inf` to `+Inf`.

Also, your code doesn't reflect your explanation in terms of ranges.

When you correct your ranges, you can use matrix indexing to assign the values without a `for` loop (which will be WAY more efficient).

eg:

This code will assign:

- -1 to range (-Inf, -1/3)
- 0 to range [-1/3, 1/3]
- 1 to range (1/3, +Inf)

.

```
x(x < -1/3) = -1;
x((x <= 1/3) & (x ~= -1)) = 0;
x(x > 1/3) = 1;
```

Note that this works because -1 < -1/3, so the first assignation doesn't overlap with the second one. Otherwise you will need an auxiliary variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was wondering if it is possible to create range based on the mean of the distribution. Say for any distribution f(x), if the mean(x) is used to create intervals then for x in [0,1] and when x in [-1,1] how would I create the range? I think for x in [0,1] : will the range be [0,-mean(x)], (-mean(x),+mean(x)], (mean(x),1] ? For x in [-1,1] what will be the range? Could you please correct  me where wrong? Thank you very much for your time.